# In cycles, how do I make slow motion blur?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a scene where someone is running and diving head first into a trap door. I want to show the expression on the character during the dive in slow motion. So to make the character not look like it's floating I need to add some motion blur.

How do I set up the scene settings so that it will get me the desired results of having motion blur, also stretching 1 second to 75 FPS instead of its normal 24 FPS?

How do I calculate the time stretching and shutter speed?

Is there anything else do I have to adjust?

Comment: Vector blur in compositing?

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry I'll skip vector blur in compositing as I want a consistent quality of motion blur throughout the project.

Comment: why not just render in 75 fps and do a slow-mo in video editing apps like premiere or any other free apps instead of taking such a pain to optimise so many settings?

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry I know it's gonna sound crazy for you but I come here specifically because I want to know how to do it in Blender.

Comment: Just asking, would it be okay for you if this is done using blender's own internal video editor? (I mean by rendering at 75 fps, and then controlling the time stretching through the video editing tab in blender)

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry I'm asking to do this in cycles.

Comment: Do you want the whole thing to be 24FPS the whole time?

Comment: @TheJeran I have a brand new problem now. My blend file is corrupt, that is why I could not understand how to get this feature to work considering I never tried it before. I used the feature with another scene works as it should.

Comment: @EricHuelin What feature? You could consider writing an answer to your own problem if you found the solution.

Comment: Though what I would have recommended was to use the time remapping blender feature or just render in 75 fps and use blender's video editor.

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/3dE-485zoCw

This 2016 YouTube video is explaining way better than the new videos.
If you call it "Time Remapping" it makes perfect sense to me than "Time Stretching" also calling the controls old and new is confusing.

Old = The original frame rate.
New = Desired frame rate.

To get a 24 FPS to run @75 you enter exactly old = 24 and new = 75.

If you keep the motion blur setting to default, it should work.

If you are not using an image sequence set your Format frame rate to 75. 
You must also change change old=75 and change new=225

Comment: I could not get my effect to work as my file is corrupt and the corruption follows when copy paste into a new file.

Comment: Well then... would you like to share your blend file? Maybe it's a bug on the specific blender version or a driver issue.